# Reset remote to specific commit in github (can't reset local and force push because of a large file)

Tags: git, github, git-bash, git-remote, git-reset

I want to reset a Github repo to a specific commit. The simplest way to do this is to reset local first and force push it to the remote. But there are large files in the project. So it's uploading all files again when force pushing. Is there any way to reset the remote by not force pushing local?

Comment: Maybe create a new remote branch with the state you want to set to, delete the old branch, push both and create a new branch from the temporary branch with the name you used and push that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the commit already exists on the remote, `git` will not upload it again.